# my code have no error but give me exception missing return statement?

Tags: java

I am making a library management system in which all the pages give me errors the 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - missing return statement

i tried another program which worked

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Signup extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection conn;
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    public Signup() {
        super("Login");
        initComponents();
        conn=javaconnect.ConnecrDb(); 
    }                                        
    private void btncreateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        try{
            String sql =(" Insert into account(Username,Name ,Password,Sec Ques, Answer) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
        pst.setString(4, (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
        pst.setString(5, jTextField5.getText());
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "new account Created");
        }catch(Exception e){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }                                         
    private void btnbackActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        setVisible(false);
        Login ob = new Login();
  ob.setVisible(true);enter code here
    }
```

the page sign up and open form to enter data and make a new account

Comment: `ob.setVisible(true);enter code here` ?

Comment: How about showing the code that doesn't work?

Comment: 1) *"my code have no error.."* Yes it does. It has a compiler error and it should be fixed prior to trying to run the code. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Comment: @Turamarth "enter code here" is a template text when adding a formatted text snippet from the question creation toolbar. Looks like OP had some issues applying formatting to the given code.

Comment: @Turamarth i did not understand you